# Celery: restrict queues for a task

Tags: python, celery, amqp

I have multiple queues, let's say these are `Q1` and `Q2`.

I also have some tasks, one of them is `T1`.

How do I configure Celery so that a worker only takes `T1` from `Q1`, and never accepts `T1` from `Q2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with celery [apps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html). Register different types of tasks to different apps and run workers on those apps only (eg. see `-A myapp` setting on celery worker command).

Alternatively you might also have success if you go down the simpler route of using [different queues](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues). So if you manage to send T1 only to queue named queue1 and T2 to queue2, you can use option `-Q queue1` on celery worker so it only takes tasks from queue1 for example.

Comment: But if my worker listens to `Q1` and expects only `T1` there, one of the client could still send `T2` into `Q1` and celery will still happily accept it because `T2` is a registered task. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am afraid the only way to go will be with different apps. Having some issues trying to run Celery + Django with multiple `celery.py` across my apps so far, but I guess it's manageable.

Comment: @Art yes, that's why I said `if you manage to send T1 only to queue named queue1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you start your worker you can specify a queue for him

```
celery -A proj worker -Q queue_name
```